# How to DRY up my switch statement which does almost the same thing in each scenario?

Tags: jquery

I have a function which conjugates a verb in latin given the word(object), voice(string), and tense(string). For reference active and passive are the voices and then present, imperfect etc... are the tenses.

Essentially my nested switch statements just run different functions with very similar names and purposes and I was wondering if there was some way to make it more efficient that I am not thinking of because it seems very redundant and clunky.

Any help would be appreciated and here is my code below:

```
function getChart(word, voice, tense) {

//Root word variables
var inf = word.inf;
var pp3 = word.pp3;
var pp4 = word.pp4;
var conj = word.conj;

//If voice is active go to the active charts for the tense
//If voice is passive go to the passive charts for the tense
switch(voice) {
    case "Active":
        switch(tense) {
            case "Present":
                activePresentConj(inf, conj);
                break;
            case "Imperfect":
                activeImperfectConj(inf, conj);
                break;
            case "Future":
                activeFutureConj(inf, conj);
                break;
            case "Perfect":
                activePerfectConj(pp3);
                break;
            case "Plu Perfect":
                activePluPerfectConj(pp3);
                break;
            case "Future Perfect":
                activeFuturePerfectConj(pp3);
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
        break;
    case "Passive":
        switch(tense) {
            case "Present":
                passivePresentConj(inf, conj);
                break;
            case "Imperfect":
                passiveImperfectConj(inf, conj);
                break;
            case "Future":
                passiveFutureConj(inf, conj);
                break;
            case "Perfect":
                passivePerfectConj(pp4);
                break;
            case "Plu Perfect":
                passivePluPerfectConj(pp4);
                break;
            case "Future Perfect":
                passiveFuturePerfectConj(pp4);
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return null;
}
```

}

Comment: If the code is complete and works, it should be posted on Code Review. This site is primarily for fixing broken code. If you add in the missing functions, this would be better posted over there.

Answer (score 0):

You could just switch on tense and pass the voice into a more general conjugation method that handles both active and passive voices.

Ex:

```
switch(tense) {
    case "Present":
        presentConj(inf, conj, voice);
        break;
    case "Imperfect":
        imperfectConj(inf, conj, voice);
        break;
    case "Future":
        futureConj(inf, conj, voice);
        break;
    case "Perfect":
        perfectConj(pp3, voice);
        break;
    case "Plu Perfect":
        pluPerfectConj(pp3, voice);
        break;
    case "Future Perfect":
        futurePerfectConj(pp3, voice);
        break;
    default:
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to hold references to functions, like this

```
//Add this to your initialization routine
var dict = {};
dict["Present"] = presentConj;
dict["Imperfect"] = imperfectConj;
dict["Future"] = futureConj;

//use this code to process a particular tense
var func = dict[tense];
if (func == undefined) return null;
func(inf, conj, voice);
```

This is just a simple example.  To make it work in your case, you'd have to define all of the functions so that they take the same parameters (even if they don't necessarily use all of them).  And you might need two dictionaries (one for passive and one for active) or you could concatenate voice and tense into a single string for the dictionary lookup.